# How to get line-level record-out on Behringer X2442-usb?

Tags: audio-recording

My band uses a Behringer X2442-usb.  We have it wired-up thus:

- Inputs going along 10 of the channels (1-8, 9 & 11 -- we don't use the stereo input capability of the higher channels.)
- We use Aux 1,2&4 out as monitor-out.

  - Aux-3 feeds into the FX channel (a little delay/reverb) that we add to the vocals, so isn't really available as a 4th monitor.
- We channel inputs through the subgroups as

  - Subgroup-1: Vocals
  - Subgroup-2: Instruments
  - Subgroup-3: Drums
  - Subgroup-4: [unused.]
- We run the same signal out both mains (that is, we don't use stereo separation.)  In fact, a typical gig only uses 1 main speaker.
- An iPod feeds the RCA "2-track"-in jacks (we use this to play tunes during pre-show setup, on-break and post-show teardown.)

What we want to do is hook up a computer to record line-level raw-audio mixer-out.  (That is, we want to just get the raw signal, mixed, but not affected by the main or subgroup volume levels.)

**IMPORTANT:** *The pictures/text in [the manual](http://www.behringer.com/assets/X1622USB_X2222USB_X2442USB_P0A0J_OI_EN_ES_FR.pdf) do not match our experience.*  Please do not quote snippets of the manual unless you have direct experience hooking things up a particular way.  I can read!  What I can't seem to do is get things to work the way I want!  :)

It *seems* like we ought to be able to just plug a computer into the USB port in back and get the sound we want there.  Indeed, this *almost* works -- but the problem is: it seems we have to choose between getting the iPod to play over the mains or recording to the computer, via the `2TR/USB to main` switch -- we can get one or the other, but not both!

We also tried plugging the computer in to the other main-out jack (using an Icicle adaptor), but that had the flaw of being speaker-level, and the recording ended up being completely clipped.

We have a separate recording device to get the "as the audience hears it" recording (a Zoom H4N, recommended! :), but we'd really like to also get the board recordings of our practices and gigs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't the '2-track out' RCA jacks work for you?

Comment: Thanks for this post, I was exactly having the same problem. I managed to get the USB audio to computer, but the level is very low. How do I increase the level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this response from care@music-group.com, Behringer's customer support wing.

*The 2TRK/USB IN is actually not the best input for a iPod. This is because there is not any independent volume control.on that input. There is not any independent volume control so that it can be used to listen to the playback of a final mixdown, without changing the volume in any way.*

> We always recommend using the stereo line level inputs for a playback
>   system.
>
> The mixer is designed so that any signal coming FROM the computer will
>   not go BACK to the computer through the USB. This is to prevent a
>   feedback loop.
>
> The 2TRK/USB IN is also not routed to the USB. You can route the
>   2TRK/USB to the analog outputs, but not to the USB.

So, I got the mini-phone to two-1/4" plug chord, plugged my iPod into channels 15/16 and record to the computer out the USB port and... ta-dah!  It all works.

Yay!